# functions call in sequence

Tags: php, oop, function, magento, object

## How this stuff works?

> $object->foo1()->foo2()->foo3();

I'm working in [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) php framework. In Magento functions are called as sequence.But, I don't understand how it works.Can anyone explain.

Comment: polynomial,phpmet = Thanks for great explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$object->foo1()->foo2()->foo3();
```

First, PHP will get a pointer to the `foo1` method from the `$object` variable. It calls this method, which then returns another object. This second object (we shall call it `$object2`) has a method `foo2()`, which is also called. `foo2()` returns another object (`$object3`), which has a method `foo3()`, which returns whatever it likes.

In some cases, `$object`, `$object2` and `$object3` are just pointers to the same object. This means that you can keep calling methods on the same class in a nice sequence.

You can achieve this quite easily:

```
class Foo
{
    public function nicely()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function formatted()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function chained()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function calls()
    {
        return $this;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->nicely()->formatted()->chained()->calls();
```

Answer (score 3):

When the methods in the class are returning values, they are returning objects of themselves.  This allows you to keep calling other methods in that class in a sequence like you posted.

```
class myClassA {

    public $str = NULL;

    public function setStr( $value ){
        $this->str .= $value;
        return $this; // This is the key to sequencing
    }

}

$myclass = new MyClassA();
$myclass->setStr("H")->setStr("E");

// If you echoed the $str variable in myClassA, you would get
// "HE"
```

Comment: I think this concept is also explained in details here... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining